# TYPO3: cleanup typo3temp/var/transient after getForLocalProcessing()

Tags: typo3

The folder `typo3temp/var/transient` of a TYPO3 installation gets flooded with gigabytes of `fal-tempfile-*` files.

After some research I suspect `EXT:exif_orientation_helper` to be the cause of the problem. The extension calls `FileInterface::getForLocalProcessing()` twice:

https://github.com/hausformat/exif_orientation_helper/blob/master/Classes/Service/ExifOrientationService.php#L69
https://github.com/hausformat/exif_orientation_helper/blob/master/Classes/Service/ExifOrientationService.php#L113

What needs to be done to delete the file after processing it?
Do I get it right, that I just need to call `FileInterface::getForLocalProcessing(false)` to prevent the `fal-tempfile-*` file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with version 0.2.1 of EXT:exif_orientation_helper.
Using `FileInterface::getForLocalProcessing(false)` is the correct approach to prevent the unnecessary files.